# Changing variable as parameter in window.open(...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code:

```
var masterHeight = $(window).height();

window.open("Agreement.aspx", "", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=800,height=800");
```

As seen above in the window.open(..), the width and height are harcoded. But I want to do something like:

```
window.open("...", "", "..., masterHeight-100");
```

I can't find a way to give that masterHeight (and masterWidth) variable as parameter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Just append the var to the string like below,

```
"location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=800,height=" + masterHeight
```

**Full Code:**

```
window.open("Agreement.aspx", 
       "",  //                       Added var masterHeight--v
       "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=800,height=" + masterHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this to perform mathematical operation:

var masterHeight = 800;
window.open("http://www.google.co.in", "", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=800,height=" + (masterHeight-400));

check this JSFiddle_http://jsfiddle.net/7ULwX/5/>

don't forget to allow popup blocker in your browser